# PostGIS point distance from polygon not 0 when on edge

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, distance

I have a pretty simple problem:

```
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((70 -40,70 -39,71 -39,71 -40,70 -40))'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -39)'), False)
```

returns 118.45656881
Shouldn't it be 0? Isn't the point on the edge of the polygon?
Why does

```
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((70 -40,70 -39,71 -39,71 -40,70 -40))'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -40)'), False)
```

return 0?

```
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70 -39.5)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70 -39)'));
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70 -39.5)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70 -40)'));
```

Why does this return two different (although only slightly) numbers?

Comment: Is this the same distance from the point to the polygon's centroid?

Comment: Is what the distance from the point to the centroid? the distance returned? 
I don't really understand your question.
`SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.5 -39.5)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -39)'), False);
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.5 -39.5)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -40)'), False);
;`
Return different values

Comment: My question is: what is the distance from the point to the centroid of the polygon and is that the same value as what you're seeing? If the answer to the second question is "yes" then we know a little more about how the ST_Distance function works.

Comment: Make sure to use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Comments are temporary.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSuZP89UdGs&t=15m04s

Comment: I don't think that this video answers my problem - the polygon and the points are both created using angular coordinates, and as such, sharing one coordinate and being within the two others, the point should be considered to intersect (and have a distance of 0) with the polygon. Like, i know that the polygon edges are not straight lines, but the point still should be on one of them, right?

Comment: change from POLYGON to LINESTRING for your second query that return 0? The actual distance is 119m 
SELECT * FROM ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(70 -40,70 -39,71 -39,71 -40,70 -40)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -40)'), False)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video explains it very well. If you take the edge in question and segmentize it

```
 SELECT st_asewkt( st_segmentize(geog,10000)) FROM ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING (70 -39,71 -39)') geog
```

you going to have the following :

[image]

the point is the the point you are asking about. The line represents the edge. North is up.

(distance measurement done by hand,no snapping)

As for the 2nd query that returns 0? It does because hte point is actually inside your polygon.

To be more clear the intersection between the two geometries is empty because they simply don't overlap.

```
select st_asewkt(st_intersection(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((70 -40,70 -39,71 -39,71 -40,70 -40))'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(70.48 -39)')))

st_asewkt
--------------
SRID=4326;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

Comment: Thank you - my mistake was thinking that polygon edges are arcs on the surface of the spheroid, not straight lines going actually through the sphere.

Comment: If you have polygon as geography, the shortest path from one corner to another is an arc on the surface. Your polygon edges do not go underground. Your real mistake is to think that the shortest arc from  POINT (70 -39) to POINT (71 -39) will follow the -39 latitude.

Comment: This is the WKT from the ST_Segmentize query: `LINESTRING (
    70 -39, 
    70.1111072111057 -39.00042152460096, 
    70.22221734714948 -39.00073767723941, 
    70.33332957252897 -39.00094845004032, 
    70.44444305154765 -39.0010538377534, 
    70.55555694845235 -39.0010538377534, 
    70.66667042747102 -39.00094845004032, 
    70.77778265285052 -39.0007376772394, 
    70.88889278889428 -39.000421524600945, 
    71 -39
)`  As you see, only the start and end points have latitude -39.